# XOR logic gate output

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates

[image]

Can someone explain me how we take this result ? This is an XOR(I think).
If we have OR we would have the result A+B. If we have OR and the circle we would have !A+!B.

Now I have XOR. How this outcome comes from?

Comment: You have a XNOR gate. Try writing its truth table.

Comment: I know it this ,but what this has to do with it?

Comment: what does this mean? ... `how we take this result?`

Comment: This is the solution that I see it on a book and I am trying to understand how it came from

Comment: Not sure what troubles you

Comment: `OR and the circle` is **not** equal to `!A+!B`

Comment: `This is the solution that I see it on a book` ... it is only a solution if there is a problem to be solved ... it looks like a logic expression to me

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

The XOR with its output inverted is… an equality comparison, sometimes called an XNOR. There is some debate about calling it XAND, although that use is out there too.

The equation you wrote is correct.

Comment: I know it is correct but I don't understand how that produced.

Comment: orthodox name will be "XNOR"

Comment: Work out the truth table. You can intuit that there will be two terms. If you’re looking for how to convert the XOR to XNOR, that would be a series of Boolean algebra steps and a final simplification to yield the two terms.

Comment: I take AB  the first like line draw cause it is the input.Then  from the second draw I have an XOR with inverted (I mean the circle o) so A'+B'. Then it takes AB from the first draw and we add + the second draw which is A' B' ? SO AB+ A'B'.that comes this result?

Comment: @e.katyia the 'first like line' doesn't signify or, the symbol for the or gate + one line means 'XOR' and the ring on the output means 'invert' you can't derive from lines, only the symbols and the rings, no smaller part has meaning (like A and Å the accent modifies the letter A but you can't get meaning from the lines making up the A).

Answer (score 0):

It's an "equals" gate (my term), one when A is the same value as B, zero otherwise.